# What part of the cylinder displaces some volume from the second liquid (which is used for the buoyant force)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics, volume

Consider a container filled with two liquids, of densities $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, such that $\rho_2 < \rho_1$. Now imagine placing a cylinder with the top base removed, of density $\rho,\space \rho_2<\rho<\rho_1$, such that the cylinder floats between the liquids. The second liquid is barely filling the cylinder, whose interior diameter is $l_1$ and whose exterior diameter is $l_2$. An illustration can be found below:

[image]

Now I am a little bit confused about the buoyancy force in liquid $2$: I thought I could express it as (assuming the height of the cylinder in liquid $2$ is $h$):

$$F_{B2} = (S_2-S_1)h\rho_2g=(\pi\frac{l_2^2}{4}-\pi\frac{l_1^2}{4})h\rho_2g=\\=\frac{\pi h\rho_2g}{4}(l_2^2-l_1^2)$$

Because the liquid actually enters the cylinder and only the walls displace a volume of liquid. **However**, the authors of the problem and my teacher claim that:

$$F_{B2}=\frac{\pi l_2^2h\rho_2g}{4}$$

Which means that the *entire* part of the cylinder that lies in liquid $2$ actually displaces a certain part of its volume, rather than the walls only. I have strong reasons to believe that I am wrong, because this is a tiny sub-part of a problem from a national contest, and the official solutions claim that the latter is correct. Which version is correct and why? What part of the cylinder displaces some of the second liquid, the walls or the cylinder itself as a whole (well, the part of them that lie in the second liquid) and why?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the marked question.  While the diagram looks similar, the previous question had an internal container with negligible volume;  and this question relies on the fact that the volume of the internal container is *not* negligible.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oh you are right. I marked it as a dupe myself, but I have to admit that I haven't read the other one thoroughly enough. I'd now vote to reopen, but I haven't got this privilege on Physics.SE :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It is not clear what your title means. What volume of which liquid is being displaced, and by what part of the cylinder : the walls alone or the walls plus liquid 2? If the issue is how to interpret the meaning of the question, then this is not a question about a physics concept. It would be helpful if you posted the text of the question.

Comment: @sammygerbil Unfortunately I cannot post the text of my question because it is in another language. Moreover, this is not a problem by itself. I stumbled upon a tiny and very specific part of a much larger problem, which I strived to explained here. I will try to edit the title to address your concerns. My issue is not how to interpret the meaning of the question.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't understand your objection. In the other question the cylinder contains wall material plus upper liquid. That is exactly the same as here. The only difference is the distribution of container mass, which is irrelevant since this is not a question about stability. I don't see anything in the other question about the internal container having *negligible volume*.

Comment: @sammygerbil:  I interpreted "thin walls" to mean that the walls of the container had "negligible volume" (though I admit that there's extra non-negligible volume down in the bottom of the container in that problem.)  Beyond that, I would also argue against this question being marked as a duplicate because it asks about a specific conceptual issue concerning this setup that is not addressed in either the previous question or its answer.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Your question is still ambiguous. (Is this *your* concern, or is this the question which the test asked?) You write *second liquid* but I think you mean *liquid 1*. And it is still not clear whether you are asking about the volume of container material or of container material plus contents which you are asking for. A less ambiguous way of stating the question is to ask *What is the volume of liquid 1 which is displaced?*

Comment: @sammygerbil I think you should read the question once again. I meant liquid $2$, not liquid $1$. And this is *my* concern. I am asking whether the walls of the cylinder displace liquid $2$ or if we should view the cylinder + the liquid inside (the cylinder's walls + the cylinder's interior) as a separate body, which, on its own, displaces liquid $2$. As noted in Michael Seifert's excellent answer, both points of view are correct, as long as we keep track of the other forces correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where your confusion lies, I think, is whether the volume of fluid 2 in the cylinder should be counted as "displacing" some volume of fluid 2 in the larger container, or whether it shouldn't be counted since that fluid would already "be there" if the cylinder wasn't there.  The answer, I think, is that the authors' answer is the conventional way to do things;  but if you were careful, you could do it your way too.

Let's consider a simpler example:  a barrel full of water is submerged in a tank of water, hanging from a spring scale above the tank.  I'll ask two questions:  what is the buoyant force on this tank?  And what is the reading of the scale?

Under the conventional definition, one would say that the buoyant force on the barrel is
$$
F_B = (V_\text{barrel} + V_\text{water}) \rho g,
$$
where $V_\text{barrel}$ and $V_\text{water}$ are the volume of the container and the volume of the water inside the tank, respectively, and $\rho$ is the density of water.  This buoyant force would be directed upwards.  Similarly, the weight of the tank would be
$$
F_G = (m_\text{barrel} + m_\text{water}) g = m_\text{barrel}g + V_\text{water} \rho g, 
$$
directed downwards.  The net upward force applied by the scale to keep the barrel from moving (which would be its reading) would then be
$$
F_S = F_G - F_B = m_\text{barrel}g - V_\text{barrel} \rho g.
$$

Now let's do it your way, and treat the water inside the barrel as part of the water in the tank.  In this case, the only volume of water that is displaced is the volume of the barrel itself, and so the buoyant force is
$$
F_B = V_\text{barrel} \rho g
$$
upwards.  The weight, meanwhile, is also *just* the weight of the barrel;  remember that we're viewing the water inside the barrel as part of the tank, so we don't have to count it:
$$
F_G = m_\text{barrel} g.
$$
The net force on the scale is therefore
$$
F_S = (m_\text{barrel} - V_\text{barrel} \rho) g,
$$
exactly as it was before.

All of this stems from the fact that the buoyant force on an object is, by definition, the weight of the displaced fluid.  If we fill some or all of that volume by the displaced fluid, we can either view this as increasing the weight of the object (while keeping the displacement constant) or decreasing the displacement of the object and thereby the buoyant force (while keeping the weight constant.)  Either way of looking at it leads to the same net change in the force on the object.

Comment: +1 Thank you for explaining their reasoning thoroughly! So it turns out it's just a matter of what system you analyse, the cylinder + the water inside or just the cylinder itself, and I've got to be careful about what weight the system in question has. (FYI I'll probably accept your answer a bit later if no others responses are posted in the meantime).